# How to use Moq to mock and test an IService

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I have a service set up as follows:

```
public interface IMyService
{
      void AddCountry(string countryName); 
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
      public void AddCountry(string countryName)
      {
          /* Code here that access repository and checks if country exists or not.
             If exist, throw error or just execute. */
      }
}
```

Test.cs

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyServiceTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Country_Can_Be_Added()
    { }

    [Test]
    public void Duplicate_Country_Can_Not_Be_Added()
    { }

}
```

How do I test `AddCountry` and moq the repository or service. I'm really not sure what to do here or what to mock. Can someone help me out?

Frameworks I'm using:

1. NUnit
2. Moq
3. ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And why would you need to use moq? You don't need to mock IService. In your case you can write your test like this:

```
[Test]
public void Country_Can_Be_Added()
{ 
  new MyService().AddCountry("xy");
}

[Test]
public void Duplicate_Country_Can_Not_Be_Added()
{ 
  Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => new MyService().AddCountry("yx"));
}
```

You would need to mock the IRepository if you had a scenario like this:

```
interface IRepository { bool CanAdd(string country); }
class MyService : IService
{
  private IRepository _service; private List<string> _countries;
  public IEnumerable<string> Countries { get { return _countries; } }
  public X(IRepository service) { _service = service; _countries = new List<string>(); }
  void AddCountry(string x) 
  {  
     if(_service.CanAdd(x)) {
        _conntires.Add(x);
     }
  }      
}
```

And a test like this:

```
[Test]
public void Expect_AddCountryCall()
{ 
    var canTadd = "USA";
    var canAdd = "Canadd-a";

    // mock setup
    var mock = new Mock<IRepository>();
    mock.Setup(x => x.CanAdd(canTadd)).Returns(false);
    mock.Setup(x => x.CanAdd(canAdd)).Returns(true);

    var x = new X(mock.Object);

    // check state of x
    x.AddCountry(canTadd);
    Assert.AreEqual(0, x.Countires.Count);

    x.AddCountry(canAdd);
    Assert.AreEqual(0, x.Countires.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(0, x.Countires.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(canAdd, x.Countires.First());

    // check if the repository methods were called
    mock.Verify(x => x.CanAdd(canTadd));
    mock.Verify(x => x.CanAdd(canAdd));
}
```

Comment: I think I'd have to mock the repository.

Comment: @Shawn Mclean - You could also Stub it.  I think I've seen more stubbed repository tests than mocked ones.

Comment: I'd recommend using Assert.Throws instead of ExpectedException.

Comment: On your concrete tests, how do you know that `yx` has already been added?  In the first test,  you are adding `xy`.  May want to rewrite the second test to call `new MyService().AddCountry("yx");` first then write the Assert.

Answer (score 3):

You test the concrete MyService. If it takes a dependency (say on IRepository) you would create a mock of that interface and inject it into the service. As written, no mocks are needed to test the service.

The point of creating the IMyService interface is to test other classes that depend on MyService in isolation. Once you know Repository works, you don't need to test it when you're testing MyService (you mock or stub it out). Once you know MyService works, you don't need to test it when you're testing MySomethingThatDependsOnMyService.